# google cloud storage temp credentials

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

If my mobile app allows users to upload directly to Google cloud storage without going through my web servers, is there a concept where temp credentials are given to users? Or are there other ways to implement this such that I do not need to expose my own credentials in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's what OAUTH is for, and OAUTH is now used with all of the Google API's.  The idea being that - just as you have indicated - there is no good way to secure your credentials on the customers' device so client key's (as opposed to server keys) do not allow direct access to your services/api's.  Instead, the client key (which you ship with your app) is used more as an identifier then a key: it allows the client to request a temporary access token from an OAUTH server (which Google runs, in this case), which can then be used to access your services/apis.

This extra layer also gives you more control, e.g. you can associate restrictions (e.g. client IP address) with a client key.

On the whole it doesn't seem like a perfect solution, and it certainly introduces additional complexity, but it is meant to address the concern your concern.

Regarding implementation on Android, you are probably using google client library for java, and it has support for Google's OAUTH2 in it.

Read here for more:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I understand correctly, you mean that for each app/client, it is assigned a client key stored on each device?

Comment: Yes.  You can generate as many client keys as you want (see 'registered apps' in the new cloud console) but the usual scheme is to have one client key for each of your client app.  And when you generate the client key you usually have to identify the client app (e.g. the certificate it was signed with) so it will only work with that client app, though I'm not sure how that would be securely enforced.

Comment: You might want to also mention [Signed URLs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs) which work really well for one-time uploads

Comment: Thanks guys. Really shone some light on it. Perhaps I can explore if it is using client key to create signed URL for every uploads. Coming from the point that credentials are not exposed and minimize the chance of misusing the cloud storage.